# Why does past participle phrase modifies object of a sentence?

Tags: past-participles, modifiers

I am confused when i read the following sentences.

1. Her cruel sisters had brought expensive new clothes for the party and laughed at her when they saw Cinderella crying , dressed in her plain, dirty rags.
2. I decided on a suitable model, priced at $2000.

I was taught that participial phrases are used to modify the subject of a sentence. But " dressed in her plain, dirty rags" modifies the object " Cinderella in sentence 1. and " price at $2000" modifies the suitable model in sentence 2.

Are these two sentences examples of dangling modifiers?

Thank you for your help!!

Comment: Participle phrases at the beginning of a sentence are anchored to the next  noun phrase, which is ordinarily the subject. Participle phrases elsewhere are anchored to the preceding noun phrase.

Comment: No, they are not danglers. The past-participial clause "Dressed in her plain, dirty rags" is a predicative (depictive) adjunct relating to "Cinderella" (the 'predicand'). Same analysis for "priced at $2000" which relates to "model".

Comment: You were taught wrong. Participial phrases can be used to describe just about any nominal constituent in a sentence, not just the subject.

Answer (score 1):

> Participle phrases at the beginning of a sentence are anchored to the next noun phrase, which is ordinarily the subject. Participle phrases elsewhere are anchored to the preceding noun phrase.
>   [- StoneyB](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/407622/why-does-past-participle-phrase-modifies-object-of-a-sentence#comment970521_407622)

Comment: This isn't quite right. It's perfectly legal for a participle phrase at the end of a sentence to modify the subject that appeared at the start of the sentence. Consider this example from http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/participlephrase.htm: *"Cooper enjoyed dinner at Audrey's house, agreeing to a large slice of cherry pie even though he was full to the point of bursting."* Per the rule you advance here, that sentence is ungrammatical (or else the *house* is male, and full to the point of bursting), yet it seems perfectly grammatical and clear to me.

Comment: @MarkAmery Can you please elaborate? To me, it seems that the trailing participle phrase "*to the point of bursting*" applies to the preceding noun "*he*", which is consistent with StoneyB's comment. If you're referring to the phrase headed by "*agreeing*", I think the preceding comma changes things.

Comment: Yeah, I'm referring to the phrase headed by "agreeing" - sorry for the ambiguity there! I agree that the preceding comma changes things - but this answer doesn't hint at that possibility, so that makes no difference to the correctness of this answer.

Comment: @MarkAmery Thanks for clarifying :) ! Feel free to add to the community wiki.